# Azure Function App Function Disappears when Adding Application Settings

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I've been following the instructions to deploy a function app from the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/data-connectors/cloudflare-using-azure-functions

I have managed to get the function app deployed from VS code and can see it successfully in the portal. However, when I try to move onto the next steps of configuring the Application settings on the portal and then restart the app, my function then disappears. If I try to redeploy again from VS code, it doesn't error out but I can no longer see my function listed.

I have tried removing the application settings that I added then redeploying the function app again, and I am able to see my function listed again. So I think the problem lies with setting the application settings, however i'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you share the function code which you have tried and which trigger you took and which application setting is trying to add?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Function App Function Disappears when Adding Application Settings

I have created Http trigger function with python runtime stack in visual studio code.

**Function code:**

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",
            status_code=200
        )
```

I have successfully deployed the function into azure portal.

[image]

I have created function app with premium app service plan.
I have added one new app setting in function app. and restarted the app.
[image]
[image]

After restarting the app also able to see the function in function app. check below:

[image]

The function runs successfully in azure portal. check below:
[image]

**Note:**

- Check that your Azure Function App is using a supported runtime version. If there have been updates to the Azure Functions runtime, there might be compatibility issues with some settings.
- If you have connection strings in your application settings, make sure they are accurate and valid. Incorrect connection strings can lead to application failures.
- check for any incorrect syntax and case sensitivity in the settings you are added.